# PHP upload class

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes, file-system

I know there are many PHP upload classes out there, but I'm comfortable with my own code, so I made a simple one here.

What do you think of my approach when `isImage` is true?

Of course a general opinion about it and any feedback will help.

```
<?php


/**
* This will allow easy handling of a php upload 
* @author: Mihai Ionut Vilcu (ionutvmi@gmail.com)
* 2-July-2013
*/
class Upload
{

    var $settings = array(
        'folder' => '.', // the folder where the images will be placed
        'isImage' => 0, // if true it will treat files as images
        'maxSize' => 2, // the max allowed size in MB
        'allowed_extensions' => array(), // an array of lowercase allowed extensions, (!) IF EMPTY ALL ARE ALLOWED (!)
        'overwrite' => 0 // if true it will overwrite the file on the server in case it has the same name
        );

    var $errors = array(); // will hold the errors
    var $success = array(); // will hold the success messages
    var $allowed_chars = "a-z0-9_.-"; // allowed chars in a file name, case insensitive

    function __construct($settings = array()) {
        // we update the settings
        $this->updateSettings($settings);
    }

    /**
     * Will process the files
     * @param  string $inputName the name of the input to be checked
     * @param  array  $settings  settings
     * @return array/string            uploaded file(s) name
     */
    function upload($inputName = 'file', $settings = array()) {
        // we update the settings
        $this->updateSettings($settings);

        if(!isset($_FILES[$inputName])) // if we have no file we have nothing to do
            return false;



        if(is_array($inputName) || is_object($inputName)) { // multiple input names
            $result = array();

            foreach ($inputName as $file) 
                $result[] = $this->handleFiles($file);

            return $result;
        } else { // single input name
            return $this->handleFiles($_FILES[$inputName]);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Will handle the files and perform validations
     * @param  array $files the array of the files from $_FILES
     * @return array        array with the uploaded files
     */
    function handleFiles($files) {
        $files = $this->reArrayFiles($files);

        if(!is_writable($this->settings['folder'])) {
            $this->errors[] = array($this->settings['folder'], " This folder is not writable !");
            return false;
        }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $result = array();
            $file['name'] = $this->filterFilename($file['name']);

            // if no filename nothing to do
            if(trim($file['name']) == '')
                continue;

            if($file['error'] > 0) {
                $this->errors[] = array($file['name'], $this->codeToMessage($file['error']));
                continue;
            }
            // we check the file size
            if($file['size'] > $this->settings['maxSize'] * 1024 * 1024) {
                $this->errors[] = array($file['name'], "The size of the file exceeds the allowed limit (".$this->settings['maxSize']."MB).");
                continue;
            }

            // check the extension, remember if settings allowed_extensions is empty it will return allow all of them
            $info = pathinfo($file['name']);
            $info['extension'] = isset($info['extension']) ? $info['extension'] : ''; // in case the file name has no extension

            if(!empty($this->settings['allowed_extensions']) && !in_array(strtolower($info['extension']), $this->settings['allowed_extensions'])) {
                $this->errors[] = array($file['name'], "This extension is not allowed !");
                continue;
            }

            // we build the path for upload
            $upload_path = ltrim($this->settings['folder'], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file['name'];

            // check if the file exists on the server
            if(!$this->settings['overwrite'] && file_exists($upload_path)){
                $this->errors[] = array($file['name'], "This file already exists, rename it !");
                continue;
            }


            if($this->settings['isImage']) { // we need to handle it as an image

                if($img = $this->imagecreatefromfile($file['tmp_name'], $function)) {
                    if($function($img, $upload_path)) { // we pass the image through a filter
                        $this->success[] = array($file['name'], "It was uploaded successfully !");
                        $result[] = $file['name'];
                    }

                    // remove uploaded file
                    @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
                } else 
                    $this->errors[] = array($file['name'], "This file is not a valid image !");


            } else { // we treat it as a normal file
                if(move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_path)) {
                    $this->success[] = array($file['name'], "It was uploaded successfully !");
                    $result[] = $file['name'];
                }
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * it will rearrange the array with the info about the files generated in $_FILES 
     * @author: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php#53240
     * @edited: Mihai Ionut Vilcu (it will handle one file also)
     * @param  array $file_post the $_FILES array
     * @return array the new array            
     */
    function reArrayFiles(&$file_post) {

        $file_ary = array();

        if(!is_array($file_post['name']))
            return array($file_post);

        $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
        $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

        for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
                $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
            }
        }

        return $file_ary;
    }

    /**
     * generates the html code for a basic upload form, it can generate the input fields only or the compleate form
     * @param  integer $number        the number of inputs
     * @param  string  $name          the name of the input(s)
     * @param  integer $complete_form if true it will generate the compleate forms insetead of just input fields
     * @param  string  $location      location where the form will send the data(in case the form is compleate)
     * @param  array   $extra         extra attributes for input(s)
     * @param  array   $extra_form    extra attributes for form
     * @return string                 html code generated
     */
    function generateInput($number = 1, $name = 'file', $complete_form = 0, $location = '?', $extra = array(), $extra_form = array()) {

        $html = $attr = $attr_form = "";

        foreach ($extra as $key => $value)
            $attr .= " $key = '$value' ";
        foreach ($extra_form as $key => $value)
            $attr_form .= " $key = '$value' ";


        for($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)
            $html .= "File ".($i+1)." 
            <input type='file' name='$name".($number > 1 ? "[]" : "")."'$attr>
            <br/>
            ";

        if($complete_form == 1)
            $html = "<form action='$location' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' $attr_form>
            ".$html."
            <input type='submit' value='Upload'>\n</form>";

        return $html;

    }


    /**
     * gets the max file size for upload allowed on the server in MB
     * @return integer the max size in MB
     */
    function getMaxUpload() {
        $max_upload = (int)(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
        $max_post = (int)(ini_get('post_max_size'));
        $memory_limit = (int)(ini_get('memory_limit'));
        return min($max_upload, $max_post, $memory_limit);
    }

    /**
     * makes sure that the file name only contains allowed chars
     * @param  string $filename file name
     * @return string           filtered file name
     */
    function filterFilename($filename) {
        return preg_replace("/[^$this->allowed_chars]/i", "_", $filename);
    }
    /**
     * it will interpret the file upload error codes
     * @param  integer $code the error code
     * @return string       error message
     */
    function codeToMessage($code) { 
        switch ($code) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: 
                $message = "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: 
                $message = "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: 
                $message = "No file was uploaded"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: 
                $message = "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: 
                $message = "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                break; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: 
                $message = "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                break; 

            default: 
                $message = "Unknown upload error"; 
                break; 
        } 
        return $message; 
    }   

    /**
     * makes sure that the settings are updated and correct
     * @param  array $settings new settings
     * @return void           
     */
    function updateSettings($settings) {
        $this->settings = array_merge($this->settings, $settings);
        $this->settings['maxSize'] = min($this->settings['maxSize'], $this->getMaxUpload());
    }


    /**
     * will create an image from a file
     * @credits: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#81831
     * @edited: Mihai Ionut Vilcu (ionutvmi@gmail.com) - added $fun 
     * @param  string  $path           path to the file
     * @param  string $fun it will hold the function required for adding image data in the file
     * @param  boolean $user_functions if true you need to have defined a function imagecreatefrombmp you can find one http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwbmp.php#86214
     * @return resource/false                  false if it fails
     */
    function imagecreatefromfile($path, &$fun, $user_functions = false)
    {
        $info = @getimagesize($path);

        if(!$info)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $functions = array(
            IMAGETYPE_GIF => 'imagecreatefromgif',
            IMAGETYPE_JPEG => 'imagecreatefromjpeg',
            IMAGETYPE_PNG => 'imagecreatefrompng',
            IMAGETYPE_WBMP => 'imagecreatefromwbmp',
            IMAGETYPE_XBM => 'imagecreatefromwxbm',
            );

        if($user_functions)
        {
            $functions[IMAGETYPE_BMP] = 'imagecreatefrombmp';
        }

        if(!$functions[$info[2]])
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(!function_exists($functions[$info[2]]))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $fun = str_replace("createfrom", "", $functions[$info[2]]);

        $targetImage = $functions[$info[2]]($path);
        // fix for png transparency
        imagealphablending( $targetImage, false );
        imagesavealpha( $targetImage, true );
        return $targetImage;
    }   

}
```

As a side note, you can also find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ionutvmi/upload-class).